# jQuery .val method need escaping?

Tags: jquery, html, escaping

Still a little confused after browsing stackOverflow and jQuery documentation.  Would I need to escape `value` if I get it from input field and modify link using string interpolation?

```
function updateLinks() {
  var value = $('.dataTables_filter input').val()
  $('.some-link').attr("href", "www.example.com/?query=" + value)
}
```

Comment: Yes. Yes, you would. The "browser" will HTML-encode the value for you, but not URL-encode it.

Comment: @frederichamidi But sending a malformed request like that would make the browser convert the URL itself upon sending... I know thats not the point, thats just the browser correcting for user mistakes.

Comment: @somethinghere, I'm afraid I don't understand your comment. If the input's value contains `&`, for instance, then it will be escaped into `&amp;`, not `%26`. Therefore, it will be interpreted as a query argument delimiter in the resulting URL, not as part of the query argument itself.

Comment: @frederichamidi Very true. Forget my comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap `value` into [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)